# Tier 4 UK visa living expenses

Tags: visas, uk

I am applying for a Tier 4 visa and the living expenses for those living outside London are 9,135 GBP, for a 1 year course. But my offer letter says an amount of 8,500 to 9,500 Pounds should be set aside for living expenses. Which one should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what the problem is. 9,135 is indeed between 8,500 and 9,500. I don't know where you got the oh-so-exact figure of 9,135, but it sounds like a statistical average. And lo and behold, this average in indeed within the range given to you in the offer letter, which was probably written by a human being, who was aware that people lifestyles and need influence how much living expenses are required – hence the low and high figures.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.Apparently my consultants thinking is that my visa might get rejected cause my funds are approx 8823GBP and not 9135GBP(as stated in tier4 guidelines). Hence the confusion

Comment: I see. Well it all depends where you got the 9,135 figure. If it's from an official source, like the visa guidelines, you'd better scrounge a little more money to reach it.

Comment: Your visa application will not be rejected merely on the fact that you have about 96% of that arbitrary number. Stay within range and focus on the other parts of your application as well

Comment: The problem is that 8,500 is lower than 9,135, which is not a statistical average but an official visa requirement. Of course, you can provide evidence for 96% of the required amount and hope the application will get though, but I doubt the OP wants to gamble like that.

Answer (score 1):

£1,015 per month (£1,265 if studying in London) is the required amount of funds for a Tier 4 visa (see [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/623341/T4_Migrant_Guidance_29_June_2017.pdf), p. 45). Evidence of living costs you have to provide is capped at 9 months, so that if you plan to stay for 9 months or more, you need the evidence for £9,135. I advise you secure **at least that amount**, unless your offer letter provides an official source for the lower amount is cites.